# Obtaining the return type of a function

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I have the following function:

```
function test(): number {
    return 42;
}
```

I can obtain the type of the function by using `typeof`:

```
type t = typeof test;
```

Here, `t` will be `() => number`.

Is there a way to obtain the return type of the function? I would like `t` to be `number` instead of `() => number`.

Comment: No, not with typeof anyways. typeof will only return "function" (*my casing might be wrong*).

Comment: It would be great if this became possible.  Sometimes you define types as you push them out of a function, and there is no (nice) way to capture this structure.

Comment: TL;DR; In 2023 the simple answer is:
type t = ReturnType<typeof test>

Answer (score 421, accepted):

**EDIT**

As of TypeScript 2.8 this is officially possible with `ReturnType<T>`.

```ts
type T10 = ReturnType<() => string>;  // string
type T11 = ReturnType<(s: string) => void>;  // void
type T12 = ReturnType<(<T>() => T)>;  // {}
type T13 = ReturnType<(<T extends U, U extends number[]>() => T)>;  // number[]
```

See [this pull request to Microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21847) for details.

TypeScript is awesome!

---

**Old-school hack**

Ryan's answer doesn't work anymore, unfortunately. But I have modified it with a hack which I am unreasonably happy about. Behold:

```ts
const fnReturnType = (false as true) && fn();
```

It works by casting `false` to the literal value of `true`, so that the type system thinks the return value is the type of the function, but when you actually run the code, it short circuits on `false`.

Comment: for flow:

    const DUMMY = ((null: any): Object) && fn()
    export type Type = typeof DUMMY

Comment: any idea why when i install 2.8 and try I get the following error:  `Cannot find name 'ReturnType'`?  using vscode

Comment: @NSjonas you need to tell vscode to use the other version. I think ont he status bar on the bottom right.

Comment: I had to do `ReturnType<typeof fn>` (the answer implies `ReturnType<fn>` is enough).

Comment: Trying to do something like this: `export function memo<R extends Function>(fn: R, resultComparator?: ResultComparator<ReturnType<R>>): R` but it's not working. Is it possible?

Comment: @spacek33z You do `ReturnType<typeof fn> when `fn` is an actual function implementation and `ReturnType<fn>` when `fn` is only a function type definition such as () => string.

Comment: Is there an analog of this for getting an argument of a function?

Comment: are you aware of how to extract `Type` from `Promise<Type>`? That's a common case for return values

Comment: Can this be done with a function that returns a Promise?

Comment: @JonasMerhej yes, it can. What's your problem? If you are getting `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type.` error, you presumably haven't tried what spacek33z has suggested.

Comment: Re Promise: I think it's `propertyName: ReturnType<infer promiseReturningFunction>;`

Comment: Regarding promises it's `type promiseType = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof promiseFn>>;`

Comment: @tslater The analog for parameter types is [Parameters<Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype).

Answer (score 156):

The easiest way in the TypeScript 2.8:

```
const foo = (): FooReturnType => {
}

type returnType = ReturnType<typeof foo>;
// returnType = FooReturnType
```

Comment: duplicate of the accepted answer

Comment: ^ but straight to the point and immediately actionable +1

Answer (score 15):

Use built-in `ReturnType`:

```
type SomeType = ReturnType<typeof SomeFunc>
```

`ReturnType` expands to:

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

Answer (score 5):

The code below works without executing the function. It's from the react-redux-typescript library (https://github.com/alexzywiak/react-redux-typescript/blob/master/utils/redux/typeUtils.ts)

```
interface Func<T> {
    ([...args]: any, args2?: any): T;
}
export function returnType<T>(func: Func<T>) {
    return {} as T;
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: RootDispatch, props:OwnProps) {
  return {
    onFinished() {
      dispatch(action(props.id));
    }
  }
}

const dispatchGeneric = returnType(mapDispatchToProps);
type DispatchProps = typeof dispatchGeneric;
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to do this (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606 for the work item tracking adding this).

A common workaround is write something like:

```
var dummy = false && test();
type t2 = typeof dummy;
```

Comment: I don't think this workaround will work anymore - likely because of control flow based type-analysis.

Comment: @JKillian you are right, the example proposed no longer works, although you can easily trick TypeScript with `!1` instead of `false` -- http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20f()%3A%20string%20%7B%0A%20return%20%2742%27%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20!1%20%26%26%20f()%0Alet%20b%3A%20typeof%20a%20%3D%20%27abc%27

Comment: ReturnType should be the answer

Comment: It looks like instead of `!1` you want `!0`. That causes the above example to work for me.

That being said one side effect of this approach is you are calling `test()` just to get the type. If `test` is a function with side effects or an expensive operation that will cause bugs or performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

If the function in question is a method of a user defined class, you can use [method decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#method-decorators) in conjuction with [Reflect Metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators) to determine the return type (constructor function) at *runtime* (and with it, do as you see fit).

For example, you could log it to the console:

```
function logReturnType(
    target: Object | Function,
    key: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
): PropertyDescriptor | void {
    var returnType = Reflect.getMetadata("design:returntype", target, key);

    console.log(returnType);
}
```

Just snap this method decorator on a method of your choice and you have the exact reference to the constructor function of the object that is supposedly returned from the method call.

```
class TestClass {
    @logReturnType // logs Number (a string representation)
    public test(): number {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

There are a few notable limitations to this approach, however:

- you need to explicitly define the return type on a method decorated as such, otherwise you'll get undefined from `Reflect.getMetadata`,
- you can only reference actual types which also exist after compilation; that is, no interfaces or generics

---

Also, you'll need to specify the following command line arguments for the typescript compiler, because both decorators and reflect metadata are experimental features as of writing this post:

```
--emitDecoratorMetadata --experimentalDecorators
```

Comment: ReturnType should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

***Edit:*** This is not needed with TS 2.8 any more! `ReturnType<F>` gives the return type. See accepted answer.

---

A variant on some of the previous answers that I'm using, which works in `strictNullChecks` and hides the inference gymnastics a bit:

```
function getReturnType<R>(fn: (...args: any[]) => R): R {
  return {} as R;
}
```

Usage:

```
function foo() {
  return {
    name: "",
    bar(s: string) { // doesn't have to be shorthand, could be `bar: barFn` 
      return 123;
    }
  }
}

const _fooReturnType = getReturnType(foo);
export type Foo = typeof _fooReturnType; // type Foo = { name: string; bar(s: string): number; }
```

It *does* call the `getReturnType` function, but it *does not* call the original function. You *could* prevent the `getReturnType` call using `(false as true) && getReturnType(foo)` but IMO this just makes it more confusing.

I just used this method with some regexp find/replace to migrate an old Angular 1.x project that had ~1500 factory functions written like this, originally in JS, and added the `Foo` etc types to all uses... amazing the broken code one will find. :)

Comment: Thanks! While sad it takes this amount of verbiage, it at least works!

Comment: @ecmanaut We don't need this anymore! In TS 2.8 you can use `ReturnType<F>` to get a functions return type. :)

Comment: The answers here diverge greatly from the example substrate of the question, making it hard to figure out how to produce a type that is the returned type of the function `test`. This answer was one of the more useful ones for only renaming `test` to `foo` (and admittedly producing a more complex return type, for kicks). Both the accepted answer and your comment are probably great if you already know how to apply them to the original example. (It’s late night here, and not immediately apparent to me what the syntax of a full ReturnType example would look like.)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have a class and you want to get the return type of a method:

```
class MeaningOfLife {
  public getMeaningOfLife() { // No explicit return type
    return 42 as const;
  }
}
```

You can access the prototype of the class in order to get the method as a function:

```
export type Answer = ReturnType<typeof MeaningOfLife.prototype.getMeaningOfLife>; // equals the literal 42
```

This is pretty nice because with little code, TypeScript will be able to infer even more complex types

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, which seems to work nicely:

```
function returnType<A, B, Z>(fn: (a: A, b: B) => Z): Z
function returnType<A, Z>(fn: (a: A) => Z): Z
function returnType<Z>(fn: () => Z): Z
function returnType(): any {
    throw "Nooooo"
}

function complicated(value: number): { kind: 'complicated', value: number } {
    return { kind: 'complicated', value: value }
}

const dummy = (false as true) && returnType(complicated)
type Z = typeof dummy
```

Comment: I don't think the function args need to be generic, since you are throwing them away anyway. `fn: (...args: any[]) => Z` is all you need.