# Determine type of dynamic module in TS 2.4

Tags: typescript

I am greatly enjoying the new dynamic module support in TS 2.4, although I ran into this small issue:

When using import().then(...) the type of the module is given.  If I need to **store the promise for later, I can't produce a type argument for Promise that conveys the module type info.**

I'm trying to do the dynamic load in a wrapper react component (where I should have been using react-router v4), and I want to start loading at constructor - and reload when component are first mounted. There is a "flickering" issue with this, but apart from that it works:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export class DashboardDynamic extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // At this point typescript knows the type of the import, including the "Dashboard" export
        this.loaderPromise = import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ './Dashboard')
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Promise<any> makes the {Dashboard} component an "any" type
        this.loaderPromise.then(({Dashboard}) => {
            this.myContent = <Dashboard {...this.props}/>
            this.forceUpdate()
        })
    }

    myContent: JSX.Element = <div />;
    loaderPromise: Promise<any> = null // PROBLEM: "any", not module type.

    render() {
        return this.myContent
    }
}
```

Anyone who knows how to type the promise so that it will hold the correct type of the dynamic module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way, although ugly:

By separating the load into a function, we can use the [wicked way to get return type from function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42549370/2684980) method to get the type.  We then get:

```js
const loadDashboard = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ './Dashboard')
const loadTypeDummy = (false as true) && loadDashboard()
type IDashboardModule = typeof loadTypeDummy
```

IDashboardModule is then a promise type that can be used to type the member variable.

UPDATE:
With **TS 2.8** you can simply do `ReturnType<typeof loadDashboard>` eliminating the need for the dummy function invocation. Check out the definition of `ReturnType`, it's awesome.

Comment: can you please post a link? None of my dynamic imports have types. Life without intellisense sucks :(

Comment: @Nickdb93 What kind of link?  With TS 2.8 this should be a breeze, but I don't have a public project to show you.  BTW: I don't envy the situation you're into...

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think that something like `typeof import('./Dashboard')` is currently possible, you could create a higher-order component that factors out the stuff you've got in `componentDidMount` while preserving types from the import.

Would be typed like this:

```
function dynamicComponent<Props>(loader: () => Promise<React.ComponentType<Props>>): React.ComponentType<Props>
```

And used like this:

```
const DynamicDashboard = dynamicComponent(() => import('./Dashboard').then(({ Dashboard }) => Dashboard)))
```

Comment: This sounds like a good option for me.  I'll post back when I get the chance to test it out.

Comment: With TS 2.8 it's become possible to do the typeof. See my answer below.