# Is there a way to get the type of a component in vuejs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am building a vuejs application in typescript. I want to make maximum use of the typings available.

Most of the time the typings and type inference just works fine.

In some pieces of code I would like to pass a reference to a specific component type. i.e.

```js
const MyComponent = Vue.extend({...});

function myFunction(someComponent: MyComponent) {
    ...
}
```

This unfortunately results in the error:

`'MyComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

Something that works is this, where I create an instance and then use typeof of that instance in the function declaration:

```js
const MyComponent = Vue.extend({...});

let myComponentInstance = new MyComponent();
function myFunction(someComponent: typeof myComponentInstance ) {
    ...
    someComponent.someProperty;
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to do this without having to create an instance of `MyComponent`? To me it feels like is should be possible as the knowledge is there.

Edit:

With the suggestion of @Bill-Naylor I got it down to this.

```js
const MyComponent =  Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            test: "test"
        }
    }
});

let dummy = () => new MyComponent();
export type MyComponentInstance = ReturnType<typeof dummy>

let test : MyComponentInstance;
let str = test.test;
```

Is it possible to get it down even more without the dummy function?

Edit2:

It is possible with `InstanceType<...>`.

This works:

```js
const MyComponent =  Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            test: "test"
        }
    }
});

export type MyComponentInstance = InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>

let test : MyComponentInstance;
let str = test.test;
```

Comment: Apparently according to this:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters
you can use interfaces for this type of thing.

Comment: Technically correct, but I do not want to maintain a interface definition next to the component while the type info is there.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that you want to get at the return type of the data parameter which you have provided to the Vue.extend() function? If so, you already have that function. I found this SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015691/obtaining-the-return-type-of-a-function
Which suggests that you can pass that function to `ReturnType<type passed to that function>`, then use that as the type in myFunction?

Comment: I managed to get something working. But I would like it even smaller. I still need a dummy function thet returns an instance of the compoment.
You are quite helpfull already :)

Comment: Looking further into the mentioned pull request I found `InstanceType`. When used like `type MyCompomentInstance = InstanceType<MyCompoment>` it is exactly what I needed. @BillNaylor Thank you very much pointing me into the correct direction.

Answer (score 31):

With the help of @BillNaylor who pointed me into the right direction I was able to find a solution.

I need to use `InstanceType<...>`

Example:

```js
const MyComponent =  Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            test: "test"
        }
    }
});

export type MyComponentInstance = InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>

let test : MyComponentInstance;
let str = test.test;
```

Comment: Very good answer, sir. Since then I have a general solution to a similar problem.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs

Comment: The last two lines of code make no sense to me.  You create a variable called "test", which has a type of MyComponentInstance.  But you don't initialize the variable "test" to anything, so it is undefined.  But then you use the variable "test" by saying "test.test".  How can this possibly work?

Comment: @deltamind106 That's not the point. The point is that typings work, and that code completion is aware of the test property of the MyComponentInstance type.