# How do I declare the type of a variable to be the type returned by an observable function?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm calling a function that returns an observable from another class, and I want to assign the value it returns to a property:

```
class MyComponent {
    prop: ???

    constructor (myService: MyService) {
        myService.observableFunc().subscribe(res => this.prop = res)
    }
}

class MyService {
    observableFunc () {
        return of({foo: "foo", bar: 123})
    }
}
```

The actual object is much more complicated and its structure is periodically changed, so I don't want to have to specify it manually. How do I declare that `prop` is of type (in this case) `{foo: string, bar: number}`?

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015691/obtaining-the-return-type-of-a-function) I got to `ReturnType<typeof MyService.prototype.observableFunc>` which returns the type of the observable itself, but I'm not sure how to get to the inner type from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ObservedValueOf`

```ts
import { ObservedValueOf, of } from 'rxjs';

type Prop = ObservedValueOf<ReturnType<MyService['observableFunc']>>

class MyComponent {
  prop: Prop
}

class MyService {
  observableFunc() {
    return of({foo: "foo", bar: 123})
  }
}
```