# How do I reuse types with long generics returned from a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to be a good TypeScripter, but I am not sure how can I deal with this scenario. Let's say I am using a library with this function signature and it returns a value. How can I reuse that value's type from that library in my own subsequent type definitions ?

```js
export function parseAbiItem<
  TSignature extends string | readonly string[] | readonly unknown[],
>(
 ....
): ParseAbiItem<TSignature> {
  ...
  return abiItem as ParseAbiItem<TSignature>
}
```

```js
import { parseAbiItem } from "...";

type Event = {
   ...
   parsedItem: [what do i put here?];
}

const event: Event = {
   ...
   parsedItem: parseAbiItem(...)
}
```

I tried copying the whole type definition, but there there has to be a better and DRYer way.

Comment: `ReturnType<typeof myFunction<CallInferedEGeneric>>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015691/obtaining-the-return-type-of-a-function

Comment: @RomanHocke Wow yes that does! I didn't know the right keywords to search for that. Thank you.